# Argument values to perl oneliners and shell scripts

Tags: perl, shell, command-line-arguments

I have a shell script with few Perl scripts and few Perl oneliners. Few Perl scripts in the shell script have oneliners in the begining which i have used through `system`. These scripts and oneliners have to take a common input. So is there a way to give argument values in the command line of shell scripts???

```
#!/bin/sh
perl test.pl
perl -ne 'print if/XXXX/ig../ZZZZZ/ig' abc.l > def.l
perl trial.pl
perl qwerty.pl
```

Here for example if the file `abc.l` used in the oneliner is the common input for `test.pl` and `trial.pl`, can I use a argument value so that I can give it in the command line to be used by the required code in the shell script????

I had tried to assign argument for a Perl oneliner but the input wasn’t accepted.

My `test.pl` code is as follows

```
system( q( perl -ne '/^.QQQ/ig && print' abc.l > data1.l) );
system( q( perl -ne '/.SSS/ig && print' data1.l > data2.l) );
open(fh,"<data3.l");
open(fh1,">>data31.l");

while (my $string =<fh>)
{
...
..
..
```

My test.pl also takes the same input `abc.l`.

Can anyone help me on this?

1. How can I use ARGV in Perl oneliners???
2. How can I give my input in command line while running the shell script???

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please ask your question in a way that makes some sense.

Comment: (1)Can I use ARGV in perl oneliners???... (2) Can I give my input in command line while running the Shell script???

Comment: If you're using a system call, you probably want to interpolate your the arguments you're passing to it.

Answer (score 1):

Perl uses the array `@ARGV` that contains the value of each shell parameter:

```
$ perl -e 'print join (":", @ARGV) . "\n" ;' this is a test
this:is:a:test
```

As you can see, all the arguments on the command line were picked up in `@ARGV`.

```
$ perl -e 'print "$ARGV[2]\n" ;' one two three four
three
```

This printed out the third parameter (since `@ARGV` count starts at `0`).

Does this answer your question?

---

#### Addendum

> EDIT : My test.pl code is as follows

```
system( q( perl -ne '/^.QQQ/ig && print' abc.l > data1.l) );
system( q( perl -ne '/.SSS/ig && print' data1.l > data2.l) );
open(fh,"<data3.l");
open(fh1,">>data31.l");

while (my $string =<fh>) {
...
```

Why not simply leave out the `system` statements, and munge your data only once:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

open my $input_file, "<", "abc.1";
open my $output_file ">>", "data31.l"
while ( my $string = <$input_file> ) {
    chomp $string;

    # These skip over the lines you don't want
    # No need to "prep" your input first

    next unless $string =~ /^.QQQ/i;
    next unless $string =~ /.SSS/ig;
    # Here be dragons
    say $ouput_file "$something";
}
close $input_file;
close $output_file;
```

This is easier to understand. You no longer have the dependence upon the `system` commands, you're not creating a bunch of temporary files, and it's way more efficient since you only go through each line once.

---

Addendum II

> Thats a good idea but i have lot of such oneliners and i am not sure if my code will work after converting the oneliners into codes.So is their ANY chance of doing it with the way i asked?????

If I understand you correctly, you want a way to use those standard *inline* programs, that you apparently cut and paste in your script, and then somehow pass the fourth argument into your main Perl program.

The answer would be *no*. The *system* command spawns a shell to run the command in a forked process. Any Perl variables in that forked process are inaccessible to the parent. You could use Perl variables in your *inline* programs, and those variables could be set in the main program.

```
my $file1 = "data1.1";
my $file2 = "data2.1"
system qq( perl -ne '/^.QQQ/ig && print' abc.l > $file1 );
system qq( perl -ne '/.SSS/ig && print' $file1 >$file2; );
```

However, if this is something you're constantly doing, then I'd highly recommend you create your own packages:

```
use local::fix_files qw(fix_QQQ fix_SSS);

fix_QQQ ( "abc.1", "data1.1" );
fix_SSS ( "data1.1", "data2.1 );
```

Comment: This answers 50% of my question...  If this oneliner is used inside a perl code then can I give in command line as "perl test.pl one two three four"

Comment: I see what you're doing with the system command. Why not simply put the `system` command code in your program? See above.

Comment: Thats a good idea but i have lot of such oneliners and i am not sure if my code will work after converting the oneliners into codes.So is their ANY chance of doing it with the way i asked?????

Answer (score 0):

The arguments to a shell script are $1, $2, etc. You can use them as is or assign them to variables like so:

```
FILE=$1
perl trial.pl $FILE
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for `$@` to pass along the parameters:

### Setup:

#### run_me

```
#!/bin/sh
perl test.pl $@
perl test2.pl $@
```

---

#### test.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "test.pl: @ARGV\n\n";
```

---

#### test2.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "test2.pl: @ARGV\n\n";
```

---

### Example Run:

```
%> ./run_me foo bar foobar
test.pl: foo bar foobar

test2.pl: foo bar foobar
```

---

## Edit/Update

> Here for example if the file "abc.l" used in the oneliner is the common input for test.pl and trial.pl, can i use a argument value so that i can give it in the command line to be used by the required code in the shell script????

I think you don't understand what's going on in the above.  "run_me" is your shell script and we are passing three values ("foo", "bar", "foobar") to it.  We are then passing those values to the perl scripts using `$@`.  If you wanted to specify the parameter being passed, instead of passing all the values to the perl script, you would use `$n`, where `n` is an integer.  So to pass "bar" to the perl script you would use `$2`.

Given your example:

```
#!/bin/sh
perl test.pl $1
perl -ne 'print if/XXXX/ig../ZZZZZ/ig' $1 > def.l
perl trial.pl
perl qwerty.pl
```

Call your script: `./shell_script abc.1`
`abc.1` should be passed to test.pl and to your *one-liner*

Comment: this really helps but what if the test.pl have an oneliner to accept the input data in the begining????  I am not able to give @ARGV in oneliner .

Comment: The `@ARGV` is used w/in perl, to send to the perl one liner (w/in the shell script) use the `$@`.  I may not be understanding you correctly, so you might want to give an example.

Comment: i have edited my post wherein i have put my sample code. It would be nice if u give an example for the oneliner thing u have commented about